# Mostrar un numero de una consulta php, mendiante un asynctask

Tags: android, asynctask

Tengo una consulta en `php` que obtiene el resultado y es un numero real (1,2,3,4...) que son el numero de registros de la tabla de la `BD`
y deseo que este numero se muestre en un `Textview.`
Mi problema es que como asignar la variable que muestra el `PHP` y asignarla al `Textview`

**Mi Asynctask es el siguiente**

```
    public class VerResultadosAsistentes extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
        public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
        ListView mostrarr;
        String pregrespcomment;
        TextView total;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_resultados_asistentes);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_asistidos);

            mostrarr=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);

            swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

            swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            });
            new AsyncRetrieve().execute();

        }
}

        private class AsyncRetrieve2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(VerResultadosAsistentes.this);
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            URL url = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pdLoading.setMessage("\tCargando asistentes...");
                pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
                pdLoading.show();

            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {

                    url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/ver_asistentes/ver_asistentes.php");

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return e.toString();
                }
                try {


                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    return e1.toString();
                }

                try {

                    int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


                    if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                        InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            result.append(line);
                        }


                        return (result.toString());

                    } else {

                        return ("unsuccessful");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "exception";
                } finally {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }


            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                pdLoading.dismiss();
                if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(VerResultadosAsistentes.this);
                    //  alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                    alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las respuestas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                    alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    alertaDeError.create();
                    alertaDeError.show();
                } else {
                    //procedimiento para el textview 
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: que error te sale?

Comment: no hay error, necesito una idea de como asignar el numero que obtengo del webservice a un textview

Comment: Agrega una variable global e inícialo, le das el valor dentro de tu `Asynctask`.

Comment: @marlonpya ya he resuelto el problema, pero de otra manera totalmente diferente ... gracias de todos modos